# Anyone have any luck with jqGrid's beforeProcessing option?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm working on implementing a uniform error handler for remote cfc methods following Ben Nadel's [model](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1567-Handling-Remote-API-Errors-With-Application-cfc-s-OnError-Event-Method.htm). Before getting to this point, I was just returning the data object to jqGrid in the form that it expects. Now, I'm returning a response object that looks like so:

```
RESPONSE.SUCCESS = "true/false"
RESPONSE.ERRORS = [array of errors]
RESPONSE.DATA = {normal data object that jqGrid expects}
```

So, I now need to massage the response object when it returns so that I have a

```
RESPONSE.SUCCESS == "true"
```

handler that, at the very least, maps RESPONSE.DATA to the data object that jqGrid expects, and also a

```
RESPONSE.SUCCESS == "false"
```

handler that does something else. My first thought was to try to implement the beforeProcessing option. However, if I add this to my initialization code:

```
beforeProcessing: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data + ' beforeProcessing was called');
},...
```

nothing ever gets logged, either on initialization or on subsequent calls. Also, if I revert to my original code and successfully reload the grid, nothing ever runs inside

```
beforeProcessing: function(){
    alert('hi');
    console.log('hi there');
},...
```

which would seem to indicate that beforeProcessing is broken.

If I can't get this to work, I'm going to try to implement ajaxGridOptions{} but can't figure out exactly what needs to be set in there - I haven't found the documentation to be much help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are a misunderstanding about the usage of Ajax and loading of grid from the server. The Ajax use HTTP protocol internally which divide clear *successful* responds from the *error* responds. If the server detect any kind of error it should set error HTTP status (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) or [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)). In 
case of HTTP status code 400 and higher the `loadError` callback will be called instead of `loadComplete`. The format of the error response can be absolutely another as the format of successful response.

So I see no reason the has all `SUCCESS`, `DATA` and `ERRORS` blocks. Boolean `SUCCESS` will be clear from the context: it's equal to `false` inside of `loadError` and it's to `true` inside of `loadComplete`. `RESPONSE.DATA` can be directly the body of the response. and the `RESPONSE.ERRORS` can be the body of the error response.

It's the reason why both `loadError` and `loadComplete` callbacks exists.

The `beforeProcessing` will be called only in case of successful response. The statement `console.log(data);` will don't display the needed information because `data` will be object and the text like `LOG: [object Object] beforeProcessing was called` which will be produced by `console.log(data + ' beforeProcessing was called');` get not much information.

**UPDATED**: I don't know ColdFusion and it's restriction in the error handling. If you really can only to return in success case the data like

```js
{
    "SUCCESS": true,
    "ERRORS": [],
    "DATA": {
        "TOTAL": xxx, 
        "PAGE": "yyy", 
        "RECORDS": "zzz",
        "ROWS": [
            {"ID": "id1", "CELL": ["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
            {"ID": "id2", "CELL": ["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

and in the case of an error

```js
{
    "SUCCESS": true,
    "ERRORS": ["Any error description"],
    "DATA": {
    }
}
```

then you can do the following.

First of all you should define [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) option of jqGrid which corresponds to successful data:

```js
jsonReader: {
    root: "DATA.ROWS",
    page: "DATA.PAGE",
    total: "DATA.TOTAL",
    records: "DATA.RECORDS",
    id: "ID"
}
```

To be able to read the error response you can place empty `"DATA"` part in the response inside of `beforeProcessing`:

```js
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    if (!data.SUCCESS) {
        // error response. we set empty "DATA"
        data.DATA = {TOTAL: 0, PAGE: 0, ROWS: []};

        // now the data.ERRORS should be processed
        alert (data.ERRORS.join(','));
    }
}
```

In the real world you should display the error messages from `data.ERRORS` in some div or dialog instead of usage of `alert`, but the general schema described above should work.

Comment: Oleg, I've added a link to the Ben Nadel blog post which explains why I'm doing this. I'm trying to incorporate a uniform error handler for all cfc remote methods, and in doing so, when Coldfusion catches an error in its onError() method, it stops processing and returns a response with a status=200 to the original ajax call. Obviously this doesn't work to let the user know that there was an internal server error.

Comment: @earachefl: It's difficult for me to comment the blog post which you reference because I don't use ColdFusion. I updated my answer. I hope if will help you. If you would have problems I ask you to post an example of successful JSON response and the corresponding jqGrid which you use and post another example with the error response from the server.

Comment: Oleg, thanks... I had forgotten about setting the jsonReader options; that did the charm. I still find that beforeProcessing simply doesn't run, so I ended up doing my (data.SUCCESS === false) processing inside loadComplete. I'd be curious to know if you've actually had success with beforeProcessing.

Comment: @earachefl: Do you use the last 4.3.1 version of jqGrid or some old version?

Comment: Oleg, yeah, that was the problem, of course... we were back on 4.1.1.

Comment: @earachefl: Then it's all clear. [The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs) describes only the last version of jqGrid.